# Retrieve (and pass) the IDs of all elements of a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to retrieve (and be able to save/use) the IDs of all elements of a certain class in Javascript.

If I wanted to select all `div` elements of class `myClass` then I believe I could do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.myClass').click(function() {
        alert('this is a div of class myClass');
    });
});
```

so I'm looking for something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.myClass').click(function() {
        let thisid = __selected__.attr('id');
        myFunc(thisid);
    });
});
```

which invokes a function using the IDs associated with each element of class 'myClass'.

Comment: `$('div.myClass').click(function() { myFunc(this.id) })` *associated with each element of class 'myClass'* did you mean "associated with that element clicked"?

Comment: What is your higher level use case? It's very easy to iterate all elements with a specific class but it's not very clear what you are hoping to accomplish here

Comment: @charlietfl For an option prompt, I generate a dialog containing several options; each option is an image contained in a div. Each div (or image, if needed) will have an id uniquely identifying the option it represents. I want it to be able to retrieve the id of any div (img) clicked within this dialog box.

Comment: So still not clear what you need exactly when one  of the `<div>` is clicked. Providing a [mcve] would be helpful and better explanation of expected results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do below
also if you pass the even object you can do event.target.id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.myClass').click(function() {
        myFunc(this.id);
        // or 
        myFunc($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: `event.currentTarget.id` is safer in case a child is clicked